# Spring boot microservice Zuul is not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I'm creating gateway using Zuul. I'm unable to start the Zuul application. Is spring boot 2.x is not supporting Zuul?

Instead of Zuul is it recommended to use Spring Cloud Gateway from 2.x onwards?

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.erps.imsx</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>zuul</name>
    <description>zuul</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>zuul</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and my resuorce file is

### application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul

server: 
  port: 9999

zuul: 
  host: 
    socket-timeout-millis: 30000
```

and my spring boot application is

### ZuulApplication.java

```
package org.erps.imsx.zuul;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZuulApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ZuulApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Can you please help why am I getting below error?

```
2018-09-08 16:56:05.405  INFO 22320 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@52e6fdee: startup date [Sat Sep 08 16:56:05 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-08 16:56:05.647  INFO 22320 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-09-08 16:56:05.663  INFO 22320 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61cba0e2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-09-08 16:56:05.924  INFO 22320 --- [           main] org.erps.imsx.zuul.ZuulApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-08 16:56:05.940  INFO 22320 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@457c9034: startup date [Sat Sep 08 16:56:05 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@52e6fdee
2018-09-08 16:56:06.627  INFO 22320 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'counterFactory' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulServerAutoConfiguration$ZuulMetricsConfiguration; factoryMethodName=counterFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulServerAutoConfiguration$ZuulMetricsConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulServerAutoConfiguration$ZuulCounterFactoryConfiguration; factoryMethodName=counterFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulServerAutoConfiguration$ZuulCounterFactoryConfiguration.class]]
2018-09-08 16:56:06.909  INFO 22320 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=b0e2af60-650b-3cff-9a4f-7683e744c3b3
2018-09-08 16:56:06.929  INFO 22320 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-09-08 16:56:06.992  WARN 22320 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/hystrix/exception/HystrixRuntimeException
2018-09-08 16:56:07.002  INFO 22320 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-08 16:56:07.008 ERROR 22320 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/hystrix/exception/HystrixRuntimeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.erps.imsx.zuul.ZuulApplication.main(ZuulApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/hystrix/exception/HystrixRuntimeException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.compiledByAjc(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.isAspect(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:78) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:104) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1033) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i guess you need Hystrix for `zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis`. either drop it or add hystrix as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the hystrix-coreXX.jar is corrupted in your .m2 folder. If not then try adding the exclusion for  hystrix-core jar to eureka, zuul and add dependency for hystrix core like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried by the above dependency sample as well. Not yet fixed

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the exception that you've got, looks like you are trying to use Netflix Hystrix without adding the necessary dependency on `pom.xml`. Either correct your code to not use Netflix Hystrix or add the necessary dependencies...

Can you please update your `pom.xml` to add the following as well?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No brother. I tried with only `Zuul`. and tried without `@EnableDiscoveryClient` also. Got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` as a dependency